# How to remove class of children using parent class in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to remove all children classes named test1 which are under intro class. So far I have done this but it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p.intro").find("div.test1").removeClass("test1");
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>


<p class="intro"><div class="test1">This is a paragraph test1.</div></p>
<button>Remove the "test1" class from intro class</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you change the `<p>` to `<div>`?

Comment: @Vel ohh thanks, it's working

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this. You need to change `<p>` to `<div>`

https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/dqbwjzeu/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".intro").find(".test1").removeClass("test1");
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="intro"><div class="test1">This is a paragraph test1.</div></div>
<button>Remove the "test1" class from intro class</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things you can change:

1. You cannot have a `div` nested in a `p` tag. Instead, nest your `p` tag in your div.
2. While it isn't needed, instead of using `.find()` you can change your selector to `"div.intro p.test1"` to get all `p` tags with the class `test1` nested in the `div` with the class `intro`

See working example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div.intro p.test1").removeClass("test1");
  });
});
```

```css
.test1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="intro">
  <p class="test1">This is a paragraph test1.</p>
  <p class="test1">This is a paragraph test2.</p>
</div>
<button>Remove the "test1" class from intro class</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `p` to a `div`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .test1 {
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("button").click(function(){
            $("div.intro").find("div.test1").removeClass("test1");
          });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="intro"><div class="test1">This is a paragraph test1.</div></p>
      <button>Remove the "test1" class from intro class</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After correcting a small mistake, changing `p` to `div` you can do something like this.

This should work:

```
$(".intro > .test1").removeClass("test1");
```